# How to declare a TypeScript module that imports another Type

Tags: typescript

In Typescript 3.6.3, I want to create a declaration for a module that doesn't have an @types package available.

One of the function parameters is defined in another module that does have types defined.

geobuf.d.ts

```
import Pbf = require('pbf');

declare module 'geobuf' {
  export function encode(obj: any, pbf: Pbf): Uint8Array;
}
```

However, when I do this, it seems that TypeScript wants to function in module augmentation mode (understandable since I have an import in the declaration file). I get the error:

```
TS2665: Invalid module name in augmentation. Module 'geobuf' resolves to an untyped module at './node_modules/geobuf/index.js', which cannot be augmented.
```

How can I create a declaration file that also references existing Typed code?

Answer (score 0):

When you write the declaration `declare module 'geobuf'` it should be in a global scope.Typescript puts it in `global.d.ts`(global namespace). which is a top level declaration in a non module (where a module is a file with at least one top level import or export).

This is called [Typescript Module Augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation)

So this `import Pbf = require('pbf');` needs to be inside that module declaration.

Hope it helps.